# Segmentation fault while commiting consumer using python confluent kafka

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

Not able to commit the consumer using confluent kafka. Facing an error "Segmentation fault", while commiting the consumer.

defined consumer with 'enable.auto.commit' = False; default.topic.config {auto.offset.reset:'earliest'}

polling the messages with timeout = 50

creating a TopicPartition object using msg.topic(), msg.partition(), msg.offset()
then commiting the consumer
consumer.commit(message=msg.value(),offsets=Topic_partition object, async=True)